# Change line length calculation of a certain character displayed with multiple glyphs

Tags: unicode, characters

I am differentiating em-dashes (—) from hypens (-) in emacs using this code in my .emacs:

```
(let* ((glyph-em-dash (make-glyph-code ?\u002D 'font-lock-function-name-face)) )        
  (aset standard-display-table 8212
    `[,glyph-em-dash ,glyph-em-dash ,glyph-em-dash]))
```

The issue is that emacs counts these characters as taking up three columns (which they do visually).  How can I tell emacs to count the em-dash as only one character when calculating line lengths, etc.?

Comment: How about using points, instead of columns, to determine the quantity of characters in a given area?  Although a character may span more than one column, it will generally be equal to only one point.  Alternatively, you can use `(current-column)` to determine where things are.

Comment: @lawllist, how can I get the column number in the mode-line and things which automatically wrap at a certain length to use points instead of columns?  Also, when would a character take up more than one point?  Do you mean unicode points?  (That might actually be a problem for me.)

Comment: "Point" is the wrong word here. You want to count *characters*, not columns. Think `length` of a string (number of chars) versus `string-width` (number of columns that would be displayed in a buffer).

Comment: Correct—characters is what I want to count.